# How to use wget inside Msys - OSGEW4W?

Tags: osgeo

I open MSYS from the OSGEO4W and type wget and I get 'command not found'. I'm using Windows 7.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you absolutely need to use "wget", you may want to have look at "curl" which is included.

`curl --help`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using msys, but I imagine that the package is not installed.

I found this site (http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/base.html) that seems to suggest you can install wget through the command line with the command

```
mingw-get install msys-wget
```

although i get the impression this would only work on full blown mingw commandline.

Failing that, I found this tutorial for installing wget manually:
http://www.transana.org/developers/setup/AudioExtract/MSYS-Win.htm (see the second half in particular)

Assuming that it is a complete emulation of bash (which i am doubting), you could also try:

firstly see if the package is installed:

```
sudo -s wget
```

If it's not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

I hope one of these solutions works, I'd hedge my bets with the first one.

Comment: `apt-get` is not part of `bash`. MSYS comes with a complete bash (which is a shell) but no package manager (such as APT, which includes `apt-get`).